# M1 Pro for software development

Tags: macbook-pro, java, apple-silicon, docker

I need to replace my Intel-based macbook, but I found out that currently, the stores are only providing the ones with M1 chipsets. So, I thought it might not be that bad with M1 Pro (10 core version), but then the old concern kicked in - Its different architecture, how will it work?

From the early days of M1, I remember there were a lot of problems with compatibility - apps were crashing, docker was not supported and a ton of other things.
Do you know, how it is now working? How hard it is to use M1 chipset in a team with mixed workstations (x86, linux, intel MacBooks), especially with following tools being used:

- Idea IntelliJ
- various java JDKs
- docker

My special concern is about docker - e.g. using testcontainers, where the image name is hardcoded in the source code of developed app. What will happen, if there is e.g. apache kafka hosted on docker (kafka does not have official arm image). Will it be emulated, or I will have to make some changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In generel, there's no problems in using an Apple M1-based computer for software development.

As always, you should ensure that the specific software you're using is compatible with the new computer. In general almost all software is compatible.

In particular there's no problem running IntelliJ and Java projects as you mention here. IntelliJ has been out in a M1 native version for almost half a year, so there's no emulation taking away performance there. Docker Desktop is also available for the M1 natively.

For Kafka, you can use the docker image here, which has native M1 support:

https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka

If the specific containers you want to use are only available for the Intel architecture, they will ofcourse have to be emulated. However, most open source software and their containers are available for ARM as well.

Comment: Thanks! You wrote "they will ofcourse have to be emulated". Is there some manual action required, or docker will do it automatically?

Comment: It's quite automatic. If there's multiple platforms to choose from and you insist on the Intel, you can use the "--platform linux/amd64" parameter to force it to run the Intel image. However note that Intel images run quite a lot slower than native ARM images, so it is much preferred to use the ARM images.